# Add values of JSON field together

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, count

I am trying to add the values of the number field. I should be getting 8, but with the code below I am getting 2 as the result.

How would you recommend that I do this?

```
"Information": [
        {
            "name": One,
            "number": 2
        },
        {
            "name": Two,
            "number": 2
        },
        {
            "name": Three,
            "number": 2
        },
        {
            "name": Four,
            "number": 2
        }
    ],
```

I'm setting up the counter as...

```
private int number;

public int getNumber() {
    return num;
}

public int[] getInformationNumber() {
    return new int[]{number};
}

for(int i = 0; i < contest.getInformation().get(i).getInformationNumber().length; i++) {
 int[] values = contest.getInformation().get(i).getInformationNumber();
 int result = 0;
 for(int value : values) {
  result += value;
 }
}
```

Is there a way that I can set private int[] number under a different name and still return the same integer? If I set private int number to private int[] number right now I cannot use getNumber().

When I Log result it reads as 2 instead of 8.

Let me know if you need me to clarify.

**ANSWER**

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < contest.getInformation().size(); i++) {
 int[] values = contest.getInformation().get(i).getInformationNumber();
 for(int value : values) {
  result += value;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without completely changing the structure of your oddly nested loops, the easiest fix is to initialize `result` to 0 outside of your outer loop so it doesn't keep getting reset.

Comment: Are you thinking there is a better way to do this?

Comment: That worked, by the way. I moved result out of my loop and changed contest.getInformation().get(i).getInformationNumber().length to contest.getInformation().size()

Comment: I'm just not sure why you're nesting your loops like you are. Your JSON only goes one level deep, so you should only need one loop to iterate through it. Perhaps I'm not fully aware of what your JSON might look like, though. If it worked, feel free to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: I'm only showing the important part of the JSON. Thanks for the help. I needed the second pair of eyes.